# Эмуляция активности пользователя c#

Tags: c#

Добрый день!
Пишу программу которая должна эмулировать активность пользователя.
Т.е. если пользователь неактивен некоторое время, то произвести какие-нибудь действия, например подвигать мышью.

Нашёл код, который выдаёт в секундах сколько пользователь неактивен

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

....

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 dwTime;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    static int last()
    {
        int t = 0;
        LASTINPUTINFO l = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        l.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(l);
        l.dwTime = 0;
        int e = Environment.TickCount;
        if (GetLastInputInfo(ref l))
        {
            int inp = (Int32)l.dwTime;
            t = e - inp;
        }
        return ((t > 0) ? (t / 1000) : 0);
    }
```

И код который может переместить курсор мыши

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
```

Время неактивности выдаётся норм, мышь сдвигается относительно старой позиции на один пункт - но вот активность пользователя это не эмулирует. Что не так?

Подскажите направление!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вам надо обнулить таймер "неактивности" пользователя, то, возможно, вам подойдёт вот это:

```
  [DllImport("CoreDll.dll")]
  public static extern void SystemIdleTimerReset();
```

Если же всё-таки надо именно переместить курсор мыщи так, чтобы обмануть детектор активности, то можно сделать это при помощи [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx), для которого есть готовая [C# обёртка](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) с открытым кодом. Ну или берите пример вызова SendInput для C#:

```
public class MouseSimulator
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct INPUT
    {
        public SendInputEventType type;
        public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MouseInputData mi;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public int uMsg;
        public short wParamL;
        public short wParamH;
    }

    struct MouseInputData
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [Flags]
    enum MouseEventFlags : uint
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
        MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
    }

    enum SendInputEventType : int
    {
        InputMouse,
        InputKeyboard,
        InputHardware
    }

    public static void ClickLeftMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }

    public static void ClickRightMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
}
```

P.S. Замечательная вещь - Google.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!

Comment: @user3216530 Если работает, то принимайте ответ.